# package Arules in R: with additional column in transactions

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I have a data file recording the `type` of transaction followed by the items in the transaction (in `basket` format):

```
type1 | eggs | chocolate | milk
type2 | milk | bread
type1 | savory | tomato
type3 | chicken
```

I would later want to remove different `type` values with appearance:

`rules = apriori(dataset, parameter = list(support= 0.1, confidence=0.2), 
   appearance = list(none = c("type=type1", "type=type2")`

How do I read in the transactions with the `type` column? The following does not work as I have data in `basket` format.

`dataset = read.transactions('data.csv', sep = '|', cols=c("type","Products"))`

Answer (score 1):

Manual page for `? read.transactions` says:

> ...
>   cols: For the ‘single’ format, ‘cols’ is a numeric or character
>             vector of length two giving the numbers or names of the
>             columns (fields) with the transaction and item ids,
>             respectively. If character, the first line of ‘file’ is
>             assumed to be a header with column names.  For the ‘basket’
>             format, ‘cols’ can be a numeric scalar giving the number of
>             the column (field) with the transaction ids.  If ‘cols =
>             NULL’, the data do not contain transaction ids.
>   ...

So this should work for your data:

```
dataset <- read.transactions('data.csv', sep = '|', cols=1)
```